# boolean expression in sh script

Tags: sh, boolean-expression

I have this simple script, which wouldn't run because of the line with `if [ ... ]`
Could anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 2 AND $# -ne 3 ]
then
    echo "Usage $0 <input> <output> [<comment>]"
    exit 1
fi;
```

Thanks!

Comment: If it is an error to call the script with the wrong number of arguments, then your code is correct to exit with a non-zero value.  However, the error message belongs on stderr.  eg `echo "..." >&2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 2 -a $# -ne 3 ]
then
    echo >&2 "Usage $0 <input> <output> [<comment>]"
    exit 1
fi
```

Or :

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ $# -ne 2 ] && [ $# -ne 3 ]
then
    echo >&2 "Usage $0 <input> <output> [<comment>]"
    exit 1
fi
```

If you'd like to use bash :

```
#! /bin/bash
if [[ $# -ne 2 && $# -ne 3 ]]
then
    echo >&2 "Usage $0 <input> <output> [<comment>]"
    exit 1
fi
```